# cakephp redirection of traffic

Tags: cakephp, redirect

how to make traffic to send 80% to groups.neighborrow.com and 20% to u.neighborrow.com.. this is developed in cakephp

Comment: You're going to have to provide a lot more detail about what you're trying to do if you want a useful answer...

Answer (score 2):

may be this is useful :

generate a random number from 1 to 100 if the number is less than or equal 80 then redirect to groups.neighborrow.com , otherwise redirect to the other site.

i guess this will achieve the 80-20 probability

Comment: This will do it.  Although I would recommend that he send everyone to groups.neighborrow.com and redirect 20% to u.neighborrow.com, so that he doesn't need to send a redirect to the 80%.  edit - he also will likely want to put in some logging here so he knows which user saw which site.

Answer (score 1):

With a load balancer, for example by using the [mod_proxy_balancer](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html) module of Apache.

Comment: A load balancer seems to be the better way of doing this.